# Powershell how to loop through 000-255 strings in if-statement

Tags: arrays, powershell, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to somehow get a for-loop to iterate automatically from 000 to 255 instead of me having to put in 255 separate elseifs. The problem I am having is that 000-255 needs to be a string and I am not sure where to put the for loop exactly.

Or maybe it's possible with an array? Like create an array first 000-255 and then iterate that in the elseif?

```
while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
    $readerLine = $reader.Readline()
    if ($readerLine -like '#*') {
        # skip line if it starts with #
    }
    elseif ($readerLine -like '000*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '001*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '002*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '003*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '004*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '005*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '006*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '007*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '008*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '009*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '010*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '011*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '012*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '013*' ){}
    elseif ($readerLine -like '014*' ){} elseif ($readerLine -like '015*' ){}
    else {
        # finally do something now 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regex to check the start of the line.

```
if ($readerLine -match '^([01]\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])') {
    # do something now 
}
```

There is no need to check for comment lines since the regex does not match them anyway.

Regex breakdown:

```
^            # start of line
(            # begin group 1
  [01]\d\d   #   0 or 1, and two more digits (covers 000-199)
  |          #   or
  2[0-4]\d   #   2, 0-4, and one more digit (covers 200-249)
  |          #   or
  25[0-5]    #   25 and 0-5 (covers 250-255)
)            # end group 1
```